# Cheerio, getting 403 when scraping

Tags: node.js, require, cheerio

I tested the code a few times using specific links on each step, and it worked, I don't know if there is some sort of mechanism preventing the request (it's my first time trying scraping/cheerio)

Now when I try to run it, I get 403 errors, for each request (507 total) so I just stop node. I was really hopeful since I did get the initial links, but when I tried running profileParse on them it broke :(

here's my retailX.js

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const profileParse = require('./profileParse')
const fs = require('fs')
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('post.csv')
const url = 'url im scraping here';


//headers
//writeStream.write(`Name, URL \n`)

rp({ 
    url:url, 
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
    },
    json:true 
  })
  .then(function(html){
    const profileUrls = []

    for (let i = 456; i < 457; i++){
        profileUrls.push('first portion of link here' + $('td > a[class="exhibitorName"]', html)[i].attribs.href)
    }

    return Promise.all(
        profileUrls.map(url => {
            return profileParse(url)
        })
    )
  })
  .then(profile => {
      //write row to csv
    writeStream.write(profile)
    console.log(profile, 'scraping done')
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //handle error
    console.log("THERE IS AN ERROR")
  });
```

second function to scrape from the second link
profileParse.js

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');

const profileParse = (url) => {
    return rp({ 
    url:url, 
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
    },
    json:true 
  })
  .then(function(html) {

const info = {
    name: $('div[class="panel-body"] > h1', html).text(),
    url: $('span[class="BoothContactUrl"] > a', html).text()
}

    return info
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    //handle error
    console.log(err, 'THERE IS AN ERROR')
  });

}
module.exports = profileParse
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's happening, but my guess would be that (assuming URLs are correct) server blocks that huge amount of requests. Try to do it in batches, e.g. 10 requests each batch. Also `return (name, url)` is not going to return what you expect it to, it should probably be `return [name, url]`

Comment: that's request getting the 403, 403 means forbidden

Comment: @paolostyle, thanks! I fixed the return. But even when I try it on just one, it gives me a 403. But when trying it earlier it gave me the correct urls, and when trying the second function on a url, it returned the correct output.

Comment: Then check if the URLs are correct. Can you access one of those 507 URLs that you got from the firs scrape from the browser? If the answer is "no" then there's something wrong with them or the site is down. One thing that comes to mind is that you forgot slash at the end of your first portion of the URL or something like that.